# Unified field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, observers, unified-theories

I had a physics thought that i'd like some clarification on. My background in math and physics isn't super sophisticated so I'd like some feedback from those who've done more research in the fields.

I was thinking about special relativity and quantum mechanics, and an abstraction popped in my head which seemed to intersect both fields but I need more clarification. In both fields, we come across this concept that 'things' are relative to the observer. In relativity, space and time, or gravity, is relative to the observer, and in quantum mechanics, particle states are relative to the observers measurement from which it collapses into reality.

I understand the mathematics are different, one being more probabilistic and the other being more deterministic. I understand that we're getting closer to unifying the fields but that specific cases of subatomic behaviour continue to evade our understanding or predicitions. I've read that there have been attempts to reevaluate the axioms of physics and math, and that we're pretty concrete on what we known. But, still this line of thinking seems like a great area to start in terms of unifying the fields. So i'd like to hear thoughts on why this is or is not a viable thought.

I've long believed that complex systems can arise from simple rules and axioms, so maybe if the idea 'truth or value being relative to the observer ' can be abstracted into an axiom then we can see if both quantum and relativity arises from that principle.

Comment: First point: physics is not built on axioms. You cannot generate physics from axioms and logic like you can build many branches of mathematics. Physics is an empirical natural science in the sense that we are bound by experimental evidence; we are not in the business of imagining universes and building laws for them, but we are trying to explain **this one**, the one we live in. Of course, branches of theoretical physics use abstractions all the time, but they are only interesting long-term if we can connect it to our own universe somehow.

Comment: Second point: special relativity and quantum mechanics are already unified under what we call quantum field theory. A large unsolved problem is how to make **general** relativity give meaningful predictions on the microscopic, i.e. quantum, scale. The observer-dependent nature of special relativity is already considered. In quantum mechanics, the state (described as an object in a Hilbert space) is **not** observer-dependent. The fact that certain observable quantities do not have sharp values before "measurement"/interaction from the outside is beside the point; the state is deterministic.

Answer (score -1):

Excellent question. For someone who professes not to have a maths or physics background, you show a very nice appreciation that both relativity and quantum mechanics are fundamentally based on relationist principles. Just as Einstein's showed that special relativity derives from the operational definition of measurement of spacetime coordinates by an observer, Heisenberg and Dirac regarded the state in quantum mechanics as the state of an observer's knowledge, and von Neumann showed that this is mathematically true in Mathematische Grundlagen der Quantenmechanik (Mathematical Foundations of
Quantum Mechanics) Beyer, 1932, which he later developed into quantum logic, showing mathematically that quantum mechanics is a general language used by an observer to describe measurement results, both actual and possible.

I had the same thought as you when I was at school, and I had the opportunity to develop the mathematical expertise at Cambridge so that I could pursue it. I have described my conclusions, conceptually, without mathematics in [The Large and the Small](https://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-ii/), and in the context of a mathematical treatment of general relativity and quantum electrodynamics in [The Mathematics of Gravity and Quanta](http://www.troubador.co.uk/bookshop/computing-science-education/light-after-dark-iii/). The core mathematical arguments showing that quantum mechanics and general relativity are indeed unified, both philosophically and mathematically, at the level of quantum electrodynamics are given in [Mathematical_Implications_of_Relationism](https://www.academia.edu/40217917/Mathematical_Implications_of_Relationism)